# Documents required to trade stocks

Tags: united-states, stocks, trading, brokerage, documents

I recently decided I would get into trading stocks and wanted to set up an Etrade account to start. When making a brokerage account, they asked for these documents from me:

- Valid (non-expired) government-issued ID or Passport
- Birth certificate
- Signed Social Security Card (front and back)

Is it normal to be asked for these documents by a brokerage? This is my first time getting into trading and would like to make sure I'm not making a mistake of giving out unnecessary personal information.

I am a US citizen.

Comment: @LeoCHan then I find that quite odd. I've never been asked the questions that you were required to answer. Are you a US citizen?

Comment: I am a US citizen

Comment: @LeoCHan  Again that is odd. I wouldn't provide those information to them then. I'd suggest calling customer service and asking why those documents are required.

Comment: @LeoCHan All you would really need to provide during registration of a brokerage account is, your name, address, employer, SSN(not the card itself) and bank account info.

Answer (score 5):

You do need to show ID and given them your SSN. I've never heard of needing to provide a birth certificate, and I don't recall ever having to actual provide a copy of a social security card. (They ask for the number, but not, in my recollection, the card itself.)